# Sonarlint complains about secure password param in Bicep SQL connection string variable

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep, sonarlint

I'm having some trouble with Sonarlint and trying to find the correct way to do what I do.

I have a Bicep module which needs a connection string to a db. I fetch a password from a keyvault before calling the module and send in the password into the module as a secure param. I then construct the connection string from that.

Everything works but sonarlint is complaining.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong, and what would be the correct way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: This isn't really related to the SQL _language_. Instead add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Not that familar with sonarlint for bicep - but in short - I think it wants you to use identity rather than including the password in the connection string. Where do you use this then? In a webapp? Maybe have a look at the keyvault properties there if you need to use passwords